# Showing Soft Keyboard on UWP No Longer Works

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

We have a number of Windows 10 UWP apps that automatically set focus to a TextBox when a page loads, using the standard Focus method. The design is to have the soft keyboard display automatically for all users when in Tablet Mode (so they don't have to explicitly "tap" into the TextBox to show the keyboard).

This has worked correctly since the initial release of Windows 10, however with the 1709/16999.x builds, the soft keyboard **will no longer show**, even when a TextBox gets focus, unless a user EXPLICITLY taps the control.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround? To reproduce this, simply make sure you have the OS build referenced, use a device in Tablet Mode, add a TextBox, set Focus to the TextBox programmatically, then deploy to the device.

What you will observe. Focus (or even SelectAll) works perfectly, however the soft keyboard will not display unless a user then (redundantly) taps the TextBox.